# Principal component analysis on a yield curve

Tags: fixed-income, statistics, yield-curve, pca, pl-attribution

When conducting principal component analysis on the yield curve, PC1  = constant (level shift), PC2 = Slope, PC3 = Curvature. How do you interpret PC>3, e.g. PC 4?

Comment: From my experience the higher PC:s have more complex shapes so the interpretation is more complicated as well. Also the above terms are not perfect, e.g. PC1 is not exactly a level factor and can show a weak slope pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 3 PCs have clear geometric interpretations: PC 1 is “level” or “parallel shift”; PC 2 is “slope” or “tilt” or “flatness / steepness” or “twist”; and PC 3 is “curvature”, “bow”, or “butterfly”.

However the higher-numbered components have less intuitive geometric interpretations, such as “double-humps” at varying tenors. Some discussion of PCs beyond 3 can be found in:  [Richard K. Crump and Nikolay Gospodinov (Federal Reserve Bank of New York). Deconstructing the Yield Curve. Staff Report No. 884 (Revised January 2022)](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/staff_reports/sr884.pdf).